# Fetching a particular record from a Core Data entity

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

How does one choose which Core Data record to fetch?

I have one entity, "Credit Card", and I have ten actual credit cards stored in that entity. How do I say "Hey, I want to fetch THAT card?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create an NSFetchRequest with a predicate that identifies the credit card you want (e.g., `id = 3` or `cardHolderName = "JOE SMITH"`), then ask the NSManagedObjectContext to execute the fetch request, returning the result set (which will contain the one card you want).

Comment: You can do this programatically, or you can create a Fetch Request in the editor as well.

Comment: Thanks! Predicate, that's the word I was looking for!

Edit: Do you know if there is a way to auto-increment an integer to create that ID number like you mentioned above?

Comment: @James Martinez: If you have a new question, you should post a new question. But look in the docs for "NSManagedObjectID" to learn how Core Data does IDs.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know which Credit Card to fetch? You have a Person entity, who has a creditCard property which refers to a CreditCard object (different entity). You don't have to ask Core Data to perform another fetch, hitting the creditCard property on the `person` reference causes it to 'fault' the object and fetch the related CreditCard entity automatically. If it's a one-to-many relationship, the property is actually an NSSet representing all the CreditCards related to that person. [Read the Core Data guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTechnologyOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009296-SW1), it's full of great information like this.